# How to manually bind data to a data list

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, datalist

I want to be able for a user to click on a button and then it runs a function and then shows the results in the data list.

i know i can get data and bind it through my tables

```
Sub BindCommsDataList(ByVal dlComms As DataList, ByVal sAddrno As String, ByVal sNameNo As String)
    Dim mySelectQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM table"
    Dim myConnection As New MySqlConnection(Session("localConn"))
    Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
    Dim myDataSet As New DataSet
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "comms")
    dlComms.DataSource = myDataSet
    dlComms.DataKeyField = "seq"
    dlComms.DataBind()
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

But how do i run a function which binds data manually

EDIT:

The data revived back will be in text format. So ideally i just want to do..

RtnDealerName.Text =  xoGetWebPage.RtnDealerName

but it says i dont have access to RtnDealerName

Comment: why you such need this ?

Comment: im trying to insrest a function on a table where a user clicks search and it goes of to another site gets data and then views it to the user, im guessing this sint the best way to do that then?

Comment: Read msdn article -Creating Templates Programmatically http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712868(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: What sort of data you are getting from the other site and how do you intend to communicate with the other site? Is the other site yours, or third party?

Comment: See Edit i am getting a few lines of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to add items directly to the DataList control, but you can use the results to build a datasource control, like a DataTable for example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));

TableRow row = table.NewRow();
row.SetField<string>("Col1", "Foo");
row.SetField<string>("Col2", "Bar");
table.Rows.Add(row);

DataList1.DataSource = table;
DataList1.DataBind();
```

Here's some simple markup for the DataList control:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Eval("Col1")%>: <%#Eval("Col2")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Edited my answer and included some basic markup for the DataList.

Comment: i get ...  'DataTable' is a type and cannot be used as an expression